# A woman is sitting in her hotel room when there is a knock at the door

Tags: story

A woman is sitting in her hotel room when there is a knock at the door. She opened the door to see a man whom she had never seen before. He said "oh I'm sorry, I have made a mistake, I thought this was my room." He then went down the corridor and in the elevator. The woman went back into her room and phoned security. What made the woman so suspicious of the man?

Comment: Hello   I have seen this on some other sites. Where did you find this?

Comment: @DEEM A friend send to me.

Comment: On this site they require the source and clear attribution. If you do not know the source you should, in my opinion, say that in the puzzle itself. Otherwise there is a chance they will put the puzzle on hold .

Comment: I think the best answer should be "Because she's met men before."

Answer (score 9):

This is a classic riddle: the woman was suspicious because

> you wouldn't knock on the door to your own room.

(Of course, this ignores:)

> the possibility that the man was sharing the room with someone else he might not have wanted to disturb.

Answer (score 7):

Is it:

> The man was dressed in orange and had a ball and chain attached to his foot?

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility, that allows for the possibility Deusovi mentions:

> The woman’s room is on the second floor of a two floor hotel. If the man’s reaction to finding he is at the wrong room is to go the elevator, that suggests he thinks he went to the “right” room but on the wrong floor. As there are only two floors and he’s just “realized” he’s on the wrong floor, he can only be going back to “his” floor: the ground floor. But if his room is on the ground floor, he would never have gotten in the elevator to begin with! Getting the wrong floor is one thing. Forgetting you don’t take the elevator to reach a room on the ground floor is another thing altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

> He didn't attempt to use his key/keycard before knocking or try it in any other doors

Another thought:

> It's the penthouse suite and there aren't any other rooms on that floor!

Comment: This is identical to @Deusovi's answer.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I don't see how - They didn't mention not using the key/card or not trying any other doors.

Comment: @Smock The reason it's suspicious to knock is that you would normally just use your key/card if it was your own room. Saying that it's suspicious to not use your key/card is essentially just a rephrasing.

Comment: There's a difference between just knocking, and attempting to use key/card and then knocking, though. You might very well knock if your key/card didn't work (maybe the maid is in). **It's not the *knocking* that's suspicious, it's the *absence of using the key/card* before knocking**. This is a different answer - it might be a very subtle difference, but different nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is:

> The woman is a part of the hotel-room staff, and the man does not recognize that her clothes are hotel staff uniforms, which means he doesn't even know what hotel he is in,And it's definitely suspicious.( her hotel room -A room she is in charge of)